# Serialize and then Deserialize DateTime using different formats

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, windows-phone-8.1, globalization

I am working at a Windows Phone 8.1 app and I have to handle the following globalization-related issue :

I am getting some DateTime value from a service and serialize it in my app for later use. The default culture is used (for example, en-US, with a datetime format MM-dd-YYYY).

If the OS changes its language, the app will use its best matching culture (let's say it will use one with this format : dd-MM-YYYY).

At app launch, when settings are to be retrieved, the app will crash because the DateTime vlue was serialized using a different format.

I am reading articles for this topic and mostly I found and read about saving (in my case serializing) a DateTime using a specific culture format. What about deserializing it afterwards, using a different format? 
I am unsure how to handle this.

Comment: Actual DateTime vars do not have a format, they have a *value*. The  Culture variation simple changes how the value/date is displayed.  It is unclear what issue you may be having (or why), without more info on the variable and perhaps how you are serializing it.

Comment: Are you serializing to JSON, XML or a custom format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cultures are for humans. You should, in general, use them for displaying information to humans, and for receiving information from humans (e.g. when they type something into an edit field). Serialization is a completely different scenario, and calls for a completely different approach.

Note that a computer does not care what culture data is in per se, but *does* need you to be consistent.

In particular, when you format (e.g. `string.Format()`, `DateTime.ToString()`, etc.) a value, you should use an overload that allows you to provide a `CultureInfo` instance, and pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (or in some unusual cases, a *specific*, hard-coded culture). When parsing information that you've formatted this way (e.g. `DateTime.TryParse()`, etc.), you should again use an overload that allows you to provide a `CultureInfo` instance, and again pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (or in those unusual cases, the *specific* hard-coded culture you used to format the text in the first place).

This ensures that your code creates consistent text from your data, and then can later reliably interpret that text, regardless of what culture settings the user is using. The serialized data may or may not make any sense to a human trying to read it; but that doesn't matter…the data wasn't formatted for the user's benefit, it was formatted for the *computer's* benefit.

If for some reason, you need the text to be formatted in a way that matches the user's current culture settings, and still have the requirement that the data can be parsed later by code running in an environment with unknown culture settings, you *must* include the name of the culture as part of the serialized data, so that the code running later can use the correct `CultureInfo` object for parsing (and again, specify it explicitly, rather than using the current culture settings). Noting, of course, that if you do it this way, even the human trying to read the data may have problems…for a human being, knowing the name of the culture does not necessarily lead immediately to being able to understand data formatted using that culture.

Comment: I *suspect* the OP may have Date data in a string and wrestling with the format as a result.

Comment: According to his post, both serialization and deserialization are under the control of his app. So he should simply perform both using `InvariantCulture`. I doubt that there's any practical reason to try to support data written by an earlier version of the app, but if he really wants to, he can add support to deserialize using some other `CultureInfo` object instead of `InvariantCulture`. The basic approach is still the same though: use an appropriate overload and provide the appropriate culture object.

Comment: My issue was indeed related to CultureInfo. The serialization is handled by the OS (storing the values as settings in the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` container).

Comment: A DateTime object is serialized as `dateTimeValue.ToString()` using the `CurrentCulture` and this was the thing which tricked me. According to MSDN, `.ToString()` uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. When changing the language of the OS, a different culture was to be used and the deserialization would fail. As a fix, I've used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, as you suggested both when saving and loading from the Settings container.